# How to make the pass a dynamic value to css class and cusmize in material UI in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i wanted to check if we can create css with dynamic values those are passed from classsName attribute .

I have a scenario where the left positions of a div will be dynamically changed based on data in react component.

Below is the scenario and wanted to check if anything like below is possible in material UI. Where the dynamic values can be passed to generate  respective css.

```
data ={left:10, top:50 }

<div className={dyanamicClass(data.left,data.top)}


-- 
dynamicClass (left,top){
return
{
 top:top+'%';
left:left+'%'
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same behavior by using the "style" prop for the dynamic part and keep the class for the common CSS part.

```
<div className="youCommonCssClass" style={{ top: `${data.top}%`, left: `${data.left}%` }} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a dynamic class means that you need to define in your CSS all the possible variant of left/top possibilities.

exemple: .dynamiqueClassleft10-top10

Which doesn't really make sens since there are alot of different combinaisons.

You should just passed directly the left and top to the style props.

```
data ={left:10, top:50 }
<div style={data}}
```